# Uncheck the checkbox by default

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am adding a new Item in SharePoint Tasks. 
But whenever I add, I see the first Item(named "Select") is checked by default. 
[image]
Is there anyway to not let this happen?

Thank You

Comment: Can anyone comment on above question?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have default value for the field.

Go to the field's settings and clear the text box for default value.

[image]

Comment: I have done that already, It does not work.

Comment: Is this a custom form with code behind, or javascript code added? OOTB forms don't auto-select a choice if no default value is set in the field's settings.

Comment: Yes this is a custom form with code behind, I tried making changes in Master file too. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check the code behind and update your question with part of code that initialise the form or sets the choices of ths field.

Comment: @SudhirKesharwani Do you have any idea about this?